# why the same rethinkdb query become very slow when many query requests happen at one time

Tags: performance, rethinkdb

I am now doing load test about rethinkdb.
and found the same query's response become very slow when many same queries be send at one time.

■the info about test.
1)rethinkdb version 2.3.0
2)send query vie java driver
3)there are Several tens of thousand records in one table.

■this is the test result.

send query thread number：
 1   2    3   4    5    6    7    8    9    10   15   20   30

query response time(ms) with send query thread number up.
466 701 964 1236 1475 1734 2009 2359 2531 2874 4234 5383 7848

■Question

query response time become longer and longer with sending query thread number up.
who can tall me why? 
anything very be helpful thank you.

my English is poor. I am sorry if some English words are wrong.

Comment: Can you share the query code? Are you using an index? What kind of server are you running this on? There are a lot of factors as to why this could be happening, could you add some more details to your question?

Comment: i am sorry can't show all of the code because the code is complexity to write here,  but main query is like as `r.db('test').table('tableA').getNearest(r.point(139.93100989999994,35.7219115),  {index: 'route.from.geometry.location', maxDist:5000})`   ,and almost other qeueries can get same result. the server is linux server machine for test. 3 db servers in cluster, all of tables are split to 3 shards. query is send to db server via rethinkdb proxy . rethinkdb proxy run on other server machine(application server).

Comment: the db servers.   model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698 v3 @ 2.30GHz, 2cores. 8G memory.

Answer (score 0):

Rethink java driver is synchronous. So, if you are using just basic driver without any additional pools of connections, your query will be sent only after completion of previous queries.

Comment: @YONGHONGZHU which one? We are using custom pool based on org.apache.commons.pool2, and it works fine.

Comment: i just cache 50 connections into memory(arraylist) when app started.  and reused the cached db connections when receiving HTTP requests. maybe this is wrong way.  let me try pool2.  @Suvitruf thank you very much.

Comment: i tried to used this rethinkdb connection pool.  but liked no much effect.https://www.versioneye.com/java/de.jakobjarosch.rethinkdb:rethinkdb-pool/2.3.0-4